# powershell oAuth problem on ExchangeOnline

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

i have a script that works fine for exchange on-prem and online with basic auth.
The problem is that my organization now accetps only oAuth metod for echangeonline.

This script is for insert a quickaction in the user logging with in his mailbox.

How i have to change the connect method to work with oauth within exchangeonline?
i'll have the same commandelets after that?

```
    Begin
    {
        Import-Module Activedirectory
    }
    Process
    {
        $curUser = $env:USERNAME
        $curDomain = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN

        $aUser = Get-ADUser -Identity "${curUser}" -Server "${curDomain}" -Properties "EmailAddress"
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($aUser.EmailAddress)) {
            throw "User ${curUser} has no Emailaddress"
        }
        $aUser.EmailAddress
        "$($aUser.GivenName) $($aUser.Surname)"
    }
}


function Connect-Exchange{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName
    )
    try {
        Connect-Exchange365 -MailboxName $MailboxName
    } catch {
        Connect-ExchangeONPREM -MailboxName $MailboxName
    }
}

function Connect-Exchange365
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName
    )
    Begin
         {


##############  NEW CODE HERE WITH OAUTH   ################

            $service = "?????????????????"

        if (!$service.URL) {
            throw "Error connecting to EWS"
        }
        else
        {
            return $service
        }
    }
}

function Connect-ExchangeONPREM
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName
    )
    Begin
         {
        ## Load Managed API dll
        ###CHECK FOR EWS MANAGED API, IF PRESENT IMPORT THE HIGHEST VERSION EWS DLL, ELSE EXIT
        $EWSDLL = (($(Get-ItemProperty -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path Registry::$(Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services'|Sort-Object Name -Descending| Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Name)).'Install Directory') + "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")
        if (Test-Path $EWSDLL)
            {
            Import-Module $EWSDLL
            }
        else
            {
            "$(get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss):"
            "This script requires the EWS Managed API 1.2 or later."
            "Please download and install the current version of the EWS Managed API from"
            "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255472"
            ""
            "Exiting Script."
            exit
            }

        ## Set Exchange Version
        $ExchangeVersion = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP2

        ## Create Exchange Service Object
        $service = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService($ExchangeVersion)

        ## Set Credentials to use two options are availible Option1 to use explict credentials or Option 2 use the Default (logged On) credentials

        #Credentials Option 1 using UPN for the windows Account
        #$psCred = Get-Credential

        ############ $creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Credentials.UserName.ToString(),$Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password.ToString())
        ############ $service.Credentials = $creds


        #Credentials Option 2
        $service.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
        $service.TraceEnabled = $true


        ## Choose to ignore any SSL Warning issues caused by Self Signed Certificates

        ## Code From http://poshcode.org/624
        ## Create a compilation environment
        $Provider=New-Object Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider
        $Compiler=$Provider.CreateCompiler()
        $Params=New-Object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
        $Params.GenerateExecutable=$False
        $Params.GenerateInMemory=$True
        $Params.IncludeDebugInformation=$False
        $Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.DLL") | Out-Null

$TASource=@'
  namespace Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy{
    public class TrustAll : System.Net.ICertificatePolicy {
      public TrustAll() {
      }
      public bool CheckValidationResult(System.Net.ServicePoint sp,
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert,
        System.Net.WebRequest req, int problem) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
'@
        $TAResults=$Provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource($Params,$TASource)
        $TAAssembly=$TAResults.CompiledAssembly

        ## We now create an instance of the TrustAll and attach it to the ServicePointManager
        $TrustAll=$TAAssembly.CreateInstance("Local.ToolkitExtensions.Net.CertificatePolicy.TrustAll")
        [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy=$TrustAll

        ## end code from http://poshcode.org/624

        ## Set the URL of the CAS (Client Access Server) to use two options are availbe to use Autodiscover to find the CAS URL or Hardcode the CAS to use

        # CAS URL Option 1 Autodiscover
        $service.AutodiscoverUrl($MailboxName,{$true})
        Write-host ("Using CAS Server : " + $Service.url)

        ## Optional section for Exchange Impersonation

        #$service.ImpersonatedUserId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $MailboxName)
        if(!$service.URL){
            throw "Error connecting to EWS"
        }
        else
        {
            return $service
        }
    }
}

function ConvertFolderid{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$hexid,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService]$service,
        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName
    )
    Begin
    {
        $aiItem = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AlternateId
        $aiItem.Mailbox = $MailboxName
        $aiItem.UniqueId = $hexId
        $aiItem.Format = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IdFormat]::HexEntryId;
        return $global:service.ConvertId($aiItem, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IdFormat]::EWSId)
    }
}
#######################
<#
.SYNOPSIS
 Gets the QuickSteps folder in a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API

.DESCRIPTION
   Gets the QuickSteps folder in a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API

  Requires the EWS Managed API from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951
.EXAMPLE
    Example 1 To Gets the QuickSteps folder in a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API
    Get-QuickStepsFolder -MailboxName mailbox@domain.com
#>
########################
function Get-QuickStepsFolder
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)] [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService]$service
    )
    Begin
    {
        #if(!$service){
            $localservice = Connect-Exchange -MailboxName $MailboxName
        #}
        $PidTagAdditionalRenEntryIdsEx = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x36D9, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Binary)
        $psPropset = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
        $psPropset.Add($PidTagAdditionalRenEntryIdsEx)
        $folderid= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Root,$MailboxName)
        try {
            $IPM_ROOT = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($localservice,$folderid,$psPropset)
        } catch {
            $localservice = Connect-ExchangeONPREM -MailboxName $MailboxName
            $IPM_ROOT = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($localservice,$folderid,$psPropset)
        }

        $global:service = $localservice

        $binVal = $null;
        $AdditionalRenEntryIdsExCol = @{}
        if($IPM_ROOT.TryGetProperty($PidTagAdditionalRenEntryIdsEx,[ref]$binVal)){
            $hexVal = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($binVal).Replace("-","");
            ##Parse Binary Value first word is Value type Second word is the Length of the Entry
            $Sval = 0;
            while(($Sval+8) -lt $hexVal.Length){
                $PtypeVal = $hexVal.SubString($Sval,4)
                $PtypeVal = $PtypeVal.SubString(2,2) + $PtypeVal.SubString(0,2)
                $Sval +=12;
                $PropLengthVal = $hexVal.SubString($Sval,4)
                $PropLengthVal = $PropLengthVal.SubString(2,2) + $PropLengthVal.SubString(0,2)
                $PropLength = [Convert]::ToInt64($PropLengthVal, 16)
                $Sval +=4;
                $ProdIdEntry = $hexVal.SubString($Sval,($PropLength*2))
                $Sval += ($PropLength*2)
                #$PtypeVal + " : " + $ProdIdEntry
                $AdditionalRenEntryIdsExCol.Add($PtypeVal,$ProdIdEntry)
            }
        }
        $QuickStepsFolder = $null
        if($AdditionalRenEntryIdsExCol.ContainsKey("8007")){
            $siId = ConvertFolderid -service $service -MailboxName $MailboxName -hexid $AdditionalRenEntryIdsExCol["8007"]
            $QuickStepsFolderId = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId($siId.UniqueId.ToString())
            $QuickStepsFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($global:service,$QuickStepsFolderId)
        }
        else{
            Write-Host ("QuickSteps folder not found")
            throw ("QuickSteps folder not found")
        }

        write-host "end of Get-QuickStepsFolder"
        write-host " ---FLD --- $($QuickStepsFolder.DisplayName)"
        return $QuickStepsFolder


    }

}

function Get-ExistingStepNames{
  param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]$QuickStepsFolder
    )
    Begin
    {
        $NameList = @{}
        $enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
        $PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x7C08,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Binary);
        $psPropset= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
        $psPropset.Add($PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM)
        #Define ItemView to retrive just 1000 Items
        $ivItemView =  New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(1000)
        $ivItemView.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemTraversal]::Associated
        $fiItems = $null
        do{
            $fiItems = $QuickStepsFolder.FindItems($ivItemView)
            if($fiItems.Items.Count -gt 0){
                [Void]$global:service.LoadPropertiesForItems($fiItems,$psPropset)
                foreach($Item in $fiItems.Items){
                    $propval = $null
                    if($Item.TryGetProperty($PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM,[ref]$propval)){
                        [XML]$xmlVal = $enc.GetString($propval)
                        if(!$NameList.ContainsKey($xmlVal.CombinedAction.Name.ToLower())){
                            $NameList.Add($xmlVal.CombinedAction.Name.Trim().ToLower(),$xmlVal)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $ivItemView.Offset += $fiItems.Items.Count
        }while($fiItems.MoreAvailable -eq $true)
        return $NameList
    }
}

function Get-ExistingSteps{
  param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]$QuickStepsFolder
    )
    Begin
    {
        $NameList = @{}
        $enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
        $PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x7C08,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Binary);
        $psPropset= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
        $psPropset.Add($PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM)
        #Define ItemView to retrive just 1000 Items
        $ivItemView =  New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView(1000)
        $ivItemView.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemTraversal]::Associated
        $fiItems = $null
        do{
            $fiItems = $QuickStepsFolder.FindItems($ivItemView)
            if($fiItems.Items.Count -gt 0){
                [Void]$global:service.LoadPropertiesForItems($fiItems,$psPropset)
                foreach($Item in $fiItems.Items){
                    $propval = $null
                    if($Item.TryGetProperty($PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM,[ref]$propval)){
                        [XML]$xmlVal = $enc.GetString($propval)
                        if(!$NameList.ContainsKey($xmlVal.CombinedAction.Name.ToLower())){
                            $NameList.Add($xmlVal.CombinedAction.Name.Trim().ToLower(),$Item)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $ivItemView.Offset += $fiItems.Items.Count
        }while($fiItems.MoreAvailable -eq $true)
        return $NameList
    }
}
#######################
<#
.SYNOPSIS
 Gets the existing Outlook Quick Steps from a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API

.DESCRIPTION
   Gets the existing Outlook Quick Steps from a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API

  Requires the EWS Managed API from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951
.EXAMPLE
    Example 1 To Gets the existing Outlook Quick Steps from a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API
    Get-QuickSteps -MailboxName mailbox@domain.com
    This returns a HashTable of the QuickSteps to access a Quickstep within the collection use the Index value eg
    $QuickSteps = Get-QuickSteps -MailboxName mailbox@domain.com
    $QuickSteps["clutter"]
#>
########################
function Get-QuickSteps{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName
    )
    Begin{
        #Connect
        #$service = Connect-Exchange -MailboxName $MailboxName -Credential $Credentials
        $QuickStepsFolder = Get-QuickStepsFolder -MailboxName $MailboxName -service $global:service
        $ExistingSteps = Get-ExistingStepNames -MailboxName $MailboxName -QuickStepsFolder $QuickStepsFolder
        Write-Output $ExistingSteps
    }
}
#######################
<#
.SYNOPSIS
 Exports an Outlook Quick Step XML settings from a QuickStep Item in a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API

.DESCRIPTION
  Exports an Outlook Quick Step XML settings from a QuickStep Item in a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API

  Requires the EWS Managed API from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951
.EXAMPLE
    Example 1 Exports an Outlook Quick Step XML settings from a QuickStep Item in a Mailbox to a file
    Export-QuickStepXML -MailboxName mailbox@domain -Name 'Name of QuickStep' -FileName c:\temp\exportFile.xml
#>
########################
function Export-QuickStepXML{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Name,
        [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$FileName
    )
    Begin{
        #Connect
        #$service = Connect-Exchange -MailboxName $MailboxName -Credential $Credentials
        $QuickStepsFolder = Get-QuickStepsFolder -MailboxName $MailboxName -service $global:service
        $ExistingSteps = Get-ExistingSteps -MailboxName $MailboxName -QuickStepsFolder $QuickStepsFolder
        if($ExistingSteps.ContainsKey($Name.Trim().ToLower())){
            $PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x7C08,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Binary);
            $psPropset= new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
            $psPropset.Add($PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM)
            $propval = $null
            if($ExistingSteps[$Name.Trim().ToLower()].TryGetProperty($PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM,[ref]$propval)){
                [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($FileName,$propval)
                Write-Host ('Exported to ' + $FileName)
            }
        }
    }
}

function Create-QuickStepFromXML
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [String]$XMLFileName
    )
    Begin
    {
        #Connect
        [xml]$QuickStepXML = Get-Content -Path $XMLFileName
        $DisplayName = $QuickStepXML.CombinedAction.Name
        $Name = $QuickStepXML.CombinedAction.Name.ToLower()
        $service = Connect-Exchange -MailboxName $MailboxName
        $QuickStepsFolder = Get-QuickStepsFolder -MailboxName $MailboxName -service $service
        $QuickStepItem = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage -ArgumentList $global:service
        $QuickStepItem.ItemClass = "IPM.Microsoft.CustomAction"
        $ExistingSteps = Get-ExistingStepNames -MailboxName $MailboxName -QuickStepsFolder $QuickStepsFolder
        if(!$ExistingSteps.ContainsKey($Name.Trim().ToLower())){
            $PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x7C08,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MapiPropertyType]::Binary);
            $enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
            $QuickStepItem.SetExtendedProperty($PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM,$enc.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $XMLFileName)))
            $QuickStepItem.IsAssociated = $true
            $QuickStepItem.Save($QuickStepsFolder.Id)
            Write-host
            Write-host ("SUCCESS Created QuickStep " + $DisplayName)
        }
        else
        {
            Write-host
            Write-host ("FAILED: QuickStep with name " + $DisplayName + " already exists")
            # throw ("Step with Name " + $DisplayName + " already exists")
        }



    }
}
#######################
<#
.SYNOPSIS
 Deletes an Outlook Quick Step from a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API

.DESCRIPTION
   Deletes an Outlook Quick Step from a Mailbox using the  Exchange Web Services API

  Requires the EWS Managed API from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951
.EXAMPLE
    Example 1 To Delete an Outlook Quick Step from a Mailbox give the name of the Quickstep
    Delete-QuickStep -MailboxName mailbox@domain -Name 'Name of QuickStep'
#>
########################
function Delete-QuickStep{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$MailboxName,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [String]$Name
    )
    Begin
    {
        #Connect
        $service = Connect-Exchange -MailboxName $MailboxName
        $QuickStepsFolder = Get-QuickStepsFolder -MailboxName $MailboxName -service $service
        $ExistingSteps = Get-ExistingSteps -MailboxName $MailboxName -QuickStepsFolder $QuickStepsFolder
        if($ExistingSteps.ContainsKey($Name.Trim().ToLower())){
            $yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes",""
            $no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No",""
            $choices = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes,$no)
            $message = "Do you want to Delete QuickStep with Name " + $Name.Trim()
            $result = $Host.UI.PromptForChoice($caption,$message,$choices,1)
            if($result -eq 0) {
                $ExistingSteps[$Name.Trim().ToLower()].Delete([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DeleteMode]::HardDelete)
                Write-Host ("QuickStep Deleted")
            }
            else{
                Write-Host ("No Action Taken")
            }

        }
        else{
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow ("No QuickStep found")
        }
    }
}



########### MAIN #############


$XML_QuickStepsContent=@'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CombinedAction Ordinal="200" Tooltip="" Icon="FileSendAsAttachment" Name="Sign as SPAM" Version="154433">
    <ActionForwardAsAttach>
        <Subject>TEST - PLS IGNORE: &lt;Subject&gt;</Subject>
        <Location/>
        <Body/>
        <Send>1</Send>
        <FlagDays>0</FlagDays>
        <Recipient>
            <EntryId>00000000DCA740C8C042101AB4B908002B2FE18201000000000000002F6F3D4D41494C2F6F753D45786368616E67652041646D696E6973747261746976652047726F7570202846594449424F484632335350444C54292F636E3D526563697069656E74732F636E3D4D62782047454152202847654F5320456D61696C20416E616C7973697320616E6420526573706F6E73652962616500</EntryId>
        </Recipient>
    </ActionForwardAsAttach>
    <ActionMoveToFolder>
        <Folder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older>
    </ActionMoveToFolder>
</CombinedAction>
'@

try {
    $mailAdddress, $username = getCurrentUserMailboxAndName

    $res = read-host "Create quick steps for ${username} mailbox ${mailAdddress}? [y|N]"
    if ("y" -eq $res.toLower()) {
        $tmpFile = New-TemporaryFile
        Out-File -FilePath $tmpFile.FullName -InputObject $XML_QuickStepsContent
        Create-QuickStepFromXML $mailAdddress -XMLFileName $tmpFile.FullName
        Remove-Item  $tmpFile
    } else {
        Write-Host
        Write-Host "Nothing to do"
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host
    Write-Host "ERROR: $($_.exception)"
}

Write-Host
$close = read-host "Press Enter to finish"

Write-Host
Write-Host "Script terminated" + $close ``
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do it probably the easiest is to use the ADAL.dll's eg

```
        Write-Verbose("Using Modern Auth")
        if ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($ClientId)) {
            $ClientId = "d3590ed6-52b3-4102-aeff-aad2292ab01c"
        }        
        Import-Module ($script:ModuleRoot + "/bin/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll") -Force
        $Context = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common")
        if ($Credentials -eq $null) {
            $PromptBehavior = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters -ArgumentList Auto  
            
            $token = ($Context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://outlook.office365.com", $ClientId , "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", $PromptBehavior)).Result
            $service.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OAuthCredentials($token.AccessToken)
        }else{
            $AADcredential = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserPasswordCredential" -ArgumentList  $Credentials.UserName.ToString(), $Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password.ToString()
            $token = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions]::AcquireTokenAsync($Context,"https://outlook.office365.com",$ClientId,$AADcredential).result
            $service.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OAuthCredentials($token.AccessToken)
        }
```

A few other examples https://ingogegenwarth.wordpress.com/2018/08/02/ews-and-oauth/ and https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2019/10/using-msal-microsoft-authentication.html